# How to call alert after ajax success data request?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".user_id").click(function(){
            jid = $(".jid").attr('id');
            var uids = [];
            $("input[name='user_id']").map(function() {
                uids.push({id: this.id, value: this.checked ? 1 : 0});
            });
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 data:{"jid":jid, "uid":uids},
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>shortlist",
                 success:function(data){
                     $(".short_emp").html(data);
                 }
            });
        });
        $(document).on('click' ,".user_idd" , function(){
            jidd = $(".jidd").attr('id');
            var uidss = [];
            $("input[name='user_idd']").map(function() {
                uidss.push({id: this.id, value: this.checked ? 1 : 0});
            });
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 data:{"jidd":jidd, "uidss":uidss},
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>interview",
                 success:function(data){
                     alert(data);
                     //$(".short_interview").html(data);
                 }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="wizard_horizontal">
    <h2>Received</h2>
    <section>
        <table class="table table-hover js-basic-example dataTable table-custom m-b-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Shortlist</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('upload_detail');
                    $this->db->where('share_with_emp','1');
                    $sqll = $this->db->get();
                    if($sqll->num_rows() > 0)
                    {
                        $resultt = $sqll->result_array();
                        foreach($resultt as $roww)
                        {
                ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h6><?php echo $roww['fname']; ?></h6>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="fancy-checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="jid" class="jid form-control" id="<?php echo $roww['jid']; ?>"/>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="user_id" id="<?php echo $roww["uid"]; ?>" class="user_id" <?php if($roww['shortlist']=='1'){ echo 'checked'; }?>><span>Shortlist</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<p>No data Found</p>";
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
    <h2>Shortlisted</h2>
    <section>
        <table class="table table-hover js-basic-example dataTable table-custom m-b-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Shortlist</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="short_emp">
                <?php
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('upload_detail');
                    $this->db->where('shortlist','1');
                    $sql_short = $this->db->get();
                    $result_short = $sql_short->result_array();
                    foreach($result_short as $fetch)
                    {
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h6><?php echo $fetch['fname']; ?></h6>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="fancy-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="jidd" class="jidd form-control" id="<?php echo $fetch['jid']; ?>"/>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="user_idd" id="<?php echo $fetch["uid"]; ?>" class="user_idd" <?php if($fetch['interview']=='1'){ echo 'checked'; }?>><span>Shortlist</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</div>
```

controller:

```
<?php   
    public function shortlist()
    {
        $jid = $this->input->post('jid');
        $uid = $this->input->post('uid');
        foreach($uid as $user)
        {
            $data = array('shortlist'=> $user['value']);
            $where = 'jid="'.$jid.'" and uid="'.$user['id'].'"';
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->update('upload_detail',$data);
        }

        if($query==true)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('upload_detail');
            $where = "jid='".$jid."' and shortlist='1'";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $sql_short = $this->db->get();
            if($sql_short->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $result_short = $sql_short->result_array();
                foreach($result_short as $fetch)
                {
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h6><?php echo $fetch['fname']; ?></h6>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="fancy-checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="jidd" class="jidd form-control" id="<?php echo $fetch['jid']; ?>"/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="user_idd" id="<?php echo $fetch["uid"]; ?>" class="user_idd" <?php if($fetch['interview']=='1'){ echo 'checked'; }?>><span>Shortlist</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>       
<?php
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>No data Found</p>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>Unable to Proceed</p>";
        }
    }
    public function interview()
    {
        $jidd = $this->input->post('jidd');
        $uidd= $this->input->post('uidss');
        echo $jidd;
        print_r($uidd);
    }
?>
```

In my code, I have table first with heading `Recieved` where I got data. Now, what am I doing when I click on `class="user_id"` it run successfully and load content over `$(.short_emp).html(data)` which is the part of heading `shortlist` inside the `<tbody class="short_emp">` but when I click on `$(".user_idd").click(function(){` then no alert are showing I don't know why? So How can I resolve this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `".user_idd"` is dynamically generated `$(document).on('click' ,".user_idd" , function(){` [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: I am doing some edit in my code @Mohamed-Yousef and I am using your code `$(document).on('click' ,".user_idd" , function(){` and when I alert it show me multiple array i.e. `comp0213083700Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => uid_20190218173353 [value] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => uid_20190218173353 [value] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => uid_20190218173353 [value] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => uid_20190218173353 [value] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => uid_20190218173353 [value] => 0 ) )`

Comment: but i want only `comp0213083700Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => uid_20190218173353 [value] => 1 ))` @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: How can I do this @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: I think instead of `print_r($uidd);` you can use `echo($uidd[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

try to add attribute data-id in an input field and call that in a function

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_idd" id="<?php echo $fetch["uid"]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $fetch["uid"]; ?>" class="user_idd" <?php if($fetch['interview']=='1'){ echo 'checked'; }?>><span>Shortlist</span>

$(document).on("click", ".user_idd", function(){

        var attr = $(this).attr('data-id'); 

        alert(attr);
});
```

hope it will work for you :)